# Work around hotlink protection for RSS images?

Tags: html, image, rss, hotlinking

By definition, RSS feeds are public, and when you display one with images, you are effectively "hotlinking" (ie reading content off the Internet rather then your local machine) those.

Is there a rule that a RSS reader could use to read those images?

Answer (score 0):

Only by turning off hotlinking protection entirely.

There are plenty of web-based RSS readers which will give `Referer` headers from the website the web app runs on.